# ng-dropdown-multiselect checkbox not working with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, multi-select

Facing a strange problem while using the **angular drop down multiselect**,"I don't know may be its a Bug" what I want is to listen the *ng-click* event when drop down is clicked but when i click on checkbox are *ng-click* not working while  outside checkbox *ng-click* works fine

**index.html**

```
                 <span class="dropdown" ng-click="populateSection(example1model,options)"   checkboxes="true"  ng-dropdown-multiselect=""
 options="example1data" selected-model="example1model" ></span>
```

**app.js**

```
  $scope.example1data = [{
    "label": "Alabama",
        "id": "AL"
}, {
    "label": "Alaska",
        "id": "AK"
}, {
    "label": "American Samoa",
        "id": "AS"
},
 $scope.populateSection=function (data) {
            console.log(data)

             for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
             {
                 $scope.models.lists[data[i].id.toString()]=[{}]

             }
         }
```

As i have enable **checkboxes=true** so i can see checkbox with dropwdown, issue is while i click on checkbox the function is not triggering but when I click on label the function triggers   So i want to trigger the function even if checkbox is clicked, any help will be highly appreciated

You can see live demo at:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/22et6sao/1476/)

clicking on label I have printed console **ng-click** works fine but on checkbox it does not show any console

Comment: Create plnkr of fiddle for batter understanding

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/22et6sao/1476/ you can see this